# Script to change Computername/hostname causing bizarre Terminal behavior

Tags: macos, terminal, bash, script

I have a script (mostly borrowed) which utilizes `scutil` to rename computers based off of values in a CSV file. It matches the serial number to a computer name, sets a variable, and then renames the `ComputerName`, `HostName`, and `LocalHostName` with the variable. For reference, the name will be `SFO-C2900-MBP`

Here's the script:

```
#!/bin/bash 

echo "-----Starting-----"

# Get serial from ioreg and assign
serial="$(ioreg -l | grep IOPlatformSerialNumber | sed -e 's/.*\"\(.*\)\"/\1/')" 

#Initialize compName to null
compName=''

#Loop through CSV looking for a match
while IFS=',' read ser loc; do
    if [ "$serial" == "$ser" ]; then
        compName=$loc
        echo "Serial Matched with name: $compName"
    fi
done < /Volumes/Macintosh\ HD/Users/Shared/Configuration/names.csv

#If compName is not null, use scutil to rename. Otherwise user must manually rename
if [[ -z $compName ]]; then
    echo "This computer was not found on the list, you must manually rename it."
else
    echo "Setting Host Name to $compName"
    scutil --set HostName $compName

    echo "Setting Computer Name to $compName"
    scutil --set ComputerName $compName

    echo "Setting Local Host Name to $compName"
    scutil --set LocalHostName $compName

fi

echo "-----Finished Renaming-----"
```

Two things are happening from this:

1) An error is thrown when the script attempts to rename the `LocalHostName`: `SCPreferencesSetLocalHostName() failed: Invalid argument`

2) The Terminal, after quit/reboot/etc, will do the following:
[image: Terminal showing Question Mark over folder, also missing hostname]
Terminal showing Question Mark over folder, also missing hostname

Setting these values manually through terminal using `scutil --set {def}` work fine and restore Terminal to its normal behavior.

I have tried the following:

- Removing the LocalHostName lines from the script
- Setting the LocalHostName value to a variable set inside the script and not the CSV file

Mostly, the script's issue is what it does to Terminal more than anything - I can work around the LocalHostName issue. Weirdly enough, when you run `scutil --get {def}` on those, Terminal outputs the correct values.

Comment: Have you considered quoting your `$compName` variable on the off chance it's being interpreted as an option? Try: `scutil --set LocalHostName "$compName"`

Comment: @IanC. Nope, same problem on the `scutil --set LocalHostName` line. I'd like to add too that the disappearance of the name in Terminal is fixed by `scutil --set HostName` being run manually via Terminal instead of the script.

Comment: And you're calling your script with `sudo <name of the script>` right?

Comment: @IanC. Yep, same result either way

Comment: Does the script set the HostName and ComputerName? Just not the LocalHostName?

Comment: @MorganR correct. It also, for whatever reason, won't register the HostName change correctly. EG if you run `scutil --get HostName` it will show, but Terminal won't work properly until you run `scutil --set HostName` with the right variable, even after reboot.

Comment: Very strange. I wrote a simple bash script that accomplishes the same task as you, but instead of looping through a CSV, I used grep and awk to isolate the computer name from the SN. I can post it below if you like? Maybe looping through an CSV is picking up a weird character which is causing your issue, although if that were the case, I'd imagine both setting the HostName and ComputerName would break too.

Comment: @MorganR Sure! Although, the reason we use the CSV is because our computer names are based off of asset tag information, which the script uses the system serial # to match against a list of known computer names.

Comment: @smoooosher @MorganR One idea to check if a strange character is getting embedded into the variable value: try adding the line `echo $compName | od -c` to the script after the "loop through the CSV" section.  (To experiment with what `od` does, try eg `echo foo | od -c` in Terminal...)

Comment: @Ashley You. Are. Amazing. There was a \r appended to the field on the CSV which was causing the rename to fail. Using `od` showed the issue and then I used `sed` to remove the extraneous character. Please post your response as an answer and I'll accept :)

Comment: Great! Very pleased to be able to help. I've written an answer. BTW, I feel that @MorganR deserves some credit here too, but sadly I don't see a way to do that in the bounty system...

Comment: Ah, I thought it was something like that, but I didn't have any idea how to verify - no need to feel guilty @Ashley! I'm glad the issue is resolved.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the comments, @MorganR wondered if the code that reads from the CSV file was including a strange character within `$compName`.

One way to test for odd, perhaps non-printable characters is to use `od`.  It has an obscure name (stands for "octal dump"), but it is useful.  It shows the detail of each character in an input stream.

I usually start by using `-c` argument, which causes `od` to output each character detail as "C-style escaped characters"... there are other arguments to output as hex, octal (still occasionally useful!), etc.

For example (notice the normally invisible `\n` is shown):

```
$ echo "foo" | od -c
0000000    f   o   o  \n                                                
0000004
```

So, if that makes sense, my suggestion is: try adding the line `echo $compName | od -c` to the script after the "loop through the CSV" section.

In the comments, the issue has turned out to be an unexpected `\r` character.  I think the likely cause for this is that the CSV file has CRLF (=`\r\n`) line endings (was it created on a Windows system perhaps?), but the `read ser loc` command in the script is expecting just LF (=`\n`).

Comment: Sorry, my first bounty. Didn't know there was an extra step beyond accepting the answer. It's all yours now :)

Answer (score 0):

I have completed the same with below string :

`compName=${loc::9};`

which actually removes 9th character of the stored variable .